# Работа за автора

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, модерация, причины-закрытия, домашки

На подсайте довольно часто появляются вопросы, подозрительно похожие на задания по информатике. С одной стороны, тематика явно "программирование", с другой - это явно встречается "в штыки" сообществом (мной в том числе).

В списке причин для флага (тревога) подходящего пункта нет. Может быть, стоит добавить такой пункт?

P.S. Вангую увеличение потока подобныx вопросов. Летняя сессия грядет!

Comment: Я уже реквестировал подобное в чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=21019838#21019838

Comment: вы случайно не снимали временно галочку с ответа 16 часов назад?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Нет. А почему возник такой вопрос?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Мне стало любопытно, почему этот вопрос именно сейчас стал важным? Вроде бы поток "домашних заданий" резко не увеличился. Или я чего-то не замечаю?

Comment: @tutankhamun: jfs получил знак за принятый ответ. Странно, что только сейчас. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened?userid=23044

Comment: @NickVolynkin Все правильно. Знак дается если "Первым дал ответ...". А первым ответ дал PashaPash. Вчера он удалил свой ответ (интересно, почему) и первым стал ответ jfs

Comment: @tutankhamun: аа, вот что. Получается, что удаленные ответы исключаются из расчета. Буду знать.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Краткий пересказ**: «похожая причина закрытия уже существовала, но ею часто злоупотребляли. „Как сделать X, используя Y?“ вопросы полезны, даже если они не содержат код».

90+% посещений Stack Overflow с интернет-поисковиков. Если вопрос полезный, то не важно, является он домашним заданием или нет.

---

На большом Stack Overflow [тема домашнего задания](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) эволюционировала несколько лет (отправлены на покой `[homework]` метка, близкие "not a real question", "minimal understanding" причины закрытия). Мы можем игнорировать накопленный опыт (на своих ошибках учиться) или ["встать на плечи гиганта"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants) и адаптировать этот опыт для нужд Stack Overflow на русском.

Главный результат: то что вопрос кем-то был задан как домашнее задание — ещё не значит, что это плохой вопрос — хотя как правило [вопросы–"домашние задания" являются плохими вопросами *по уже **существующим** критериям*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Например, следующие признаки можно встретить во многих вопросах-"домашних заданиях":

- *полное отсутствие* демонстрации усилий со стороны автора вопроса — *голосовать «против»*
- не слишком полезен из-за искусственных ограничений не встречающихся на практике — *голосовать «против»*
- содержит несколько отдельных вопросов — *оставить комментарий к вопросу*, чтобы автор сначала попытался решить задачу самостоятельно, и при возникновении конкретных проблем, задавал бы более специфичные вопросы
- не хватает контекста, чтобы краткий хороший ответ оставить — *закрыть как слишком обширный или неясный*

Тема [«Работа за автора» является популярной](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/4279). Я солидарен с [мнением  @Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason#comment106655_274630):

> Amusingly, this was the original intent of the old "minimal
>   understanding" OT reason... Too many cooks spoiled the broth on that
>   one. Still, worth being wary of the problems suffered there -
>   clearly-written "how do I do X using Y?" questions are pretty useful,
>   even if they don't contain code.

и из [Make it easier to close job shop “gimme teh codez” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/4279):

> [Your Common Sense was right:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251897/off-topic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-out-of-the-way-but-not-via-closure/) closure is the wrong tool for this job.
>   There are too many of these questions to close even if we could
>   identify them accurately, and we're universally bad at identifying
>   them accurately. And in our efforts to do so, we've damaged the site,
>   created divisions between people who would've been working toward the
>   same ends, and wasted a tremendous amount of time and effort.
>
> Closing is a perfectly good tool for off-topic questions, a reasonable
>   tool for unclear or subjective questions, and even a decent enough
>   tool for duplicates. But it simply doesn't work for these, and after
>   years of trying to make it work it's time we admitted that.

Comment: А что делать с вопросами типа «я не знаю паскаль, вот вам программа на паскале, переведите на C»? Просто минусовать? Мне кажется, стоит сразу закрывать, иначе автор не поймёт, что **такие вопросы в принципе не приветствуются**.

Comment: @VladD: я помню пару подобных вопросов (с разным кодом). Я не был уверен, что с ними делать. Сейчас, я бы закрывал как "слишком обширный" -- так как, чтобы сделать ответ полезным другим участникам (упомянутым 90+%) -- пришлось бы изложить как Паскаль так и С в одном ответе (это больше для пару книг подходит). Хотя если у автора более специфичный вопрос: скажем "как <вот такую конкретную идиому Паскаля>, лучше всего выразить в С", то это нормальный вопрос -- это допускает неидеальное знание обоих языков. Ситуация аналогична более общей категории -- "Напишите мне программу".

Comment: На мой вкус, хороший кандидат в категорию «работа за автора». Возможно, надо уточнить формулировку, чтобы под неё не попадали и нормальные вопросы.

Comment: @VladD: может быть я не достаточно категорично высказался, так что скажу явно: *«работа за автора» -- это плохая причина для закрытия вопроса* -- ею будут злоупотреблять ("нет демонстрации усилий -- закрыть", даже если сам вопрос полезен) и **она не нужна** так как с плохими вопросами можно уже существующими инструментами бороться. Или если существующих инструментов не хватает, то нужно предлагать более узкие признаки, которые сами по себе указывают на плохой вопрос (сложнее злоупотребить и выплеснуть ребёнка..)

Comment: @VladD: перечитал ваш последний комментарий -- мы снова говорим об одном и том же, но разными словами. Хотя у меня более мягкая точка зрения -- я допускаю, что новая причина закрытия иногда может и "нормальные вопросы" затрагивать, главное чтобы доля таких вопросов *на практике* не была большой по сравнению с пользой от закрытия плохих вопросов. У вас более строгая точка зрения: "не попадали и нормальные вопросы" (как спам vs. "нормальное письмо" -- лучше иногда на спам посмотреть чем "нормальное письмо" в спам отправить).

Comment: Именно так. Мне кажется, даже такую причину закрытия как «работа за автора» можно «спасти», если переформулировать её более конкретно.

Comment: Можете взглянуть на сий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574265 и увидеть 14 минусов (я НЕ в их числе), 5 проголосовавших за закрытие (я НЕ в их числе) и удален самим  Nicolas Chabanovsk ..... Подобных вопросов не мало..... По-моему сообщество явно дает понять как оно оценивает такие вопросы.... Не один человек, не два, не три, а много активных её участников. Похоже стоит немного пересмотреть взгляды на такие вопросы.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский цитату (прямую) из моего ответа приведите с которой вы не согласны. Кстати никто вам не запрещает ещё один ответ (или несколько опубликовать) здесь, чтобы люди могли проголосовать

Comment: @jfs вы читать умеете хорошо? `14 минусов (я НЕ в их числе), 5 проголосовавших за закрытие (я НЕ в их числе) и удален самим Nicolas Chabanovsky` - ......и "**СООБЩЕСТВО** явно дает понять как оно оценивает такие вопросы" .........что из этого вам конкретно не ясно? Причем тут я?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и какое это имеет отношение к моему ответу? Какое именно утверждение в нём *по вашему мнению*  противоречит сообществу. Приведите прямую цитату (конкретное предложение). Почему вы боитесь свой ответ о "работе за автора" оставить и посмотреть как люди проголосуют. (За мой ответ +27 -2 на данный момент—ваш ход).

Comment: @jfs меня разводить не стоит. Я вам не пьяненькая школьница на выпускном........по вопросу: вы пишите "Я солидарен с мнением @Shog9♦: .....questions are pretty useful, even if they don't contain code." и делаете упор что за это проголосовали.....Могу сказать, что во  раньше и за вопросы в стиле [Как учить ребенка программировать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/) голосовали +36.....времена меняются.......Сейчас октябрь 2016..... И да, оно противоречит сообществу, т.к. (повторю третий раз): "**СООБЩЕСТВО** явно дает понять как оно оценивает такие вопросы"

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ваше утверждение что Shog9 не прав, что любой вопрос, если он не содержит кода следует закрыть с формулировкой "работа за автора"? Так? Смысла жирным выделять слово сообщество не вижу. Это по вашему что-то доказывает? Не убедительно. Опубликуйте ответ и дайте сообществу проголосовать, если вы думаете что устарели голоса. Не нужно пытаться за **СООБЩЕСТВО** говорить. Говорите за себя.

Comment: @jfs `Не нужно пытаться за СООБЩЕСТВО говорить. Говорите за себя`.......то есть вам недостаточно маленького примера выше из ссылки? Ну извините. тогда смысл с вами о чем-то говорить нет, если всё сводится к тому, что это я один недовольный............... мета, в отношении голосования сообщества, изжила себя. В основном она сейчас используется для публикации дефектов и некоторых мелких вопросов. Голосует тут десяток человек, а сообщество из сотен человек, большинство коих не заходят на мету, в принципе (по разным причинам).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пример ваш не открывается у меня (наверно потому что удалён). Я предположу, что он был вопросом без кода (на основании выбранной вами цитаты), если это не так то поправьте. И на основании того что этот конкретный вопрос был заминусован и закрыт, вы считаете что *все* вопросы без кода должны быть закрыты? Не искажаю ли я вашу точку зрения? А излагать явно ввиде ответа вы свою точку зрения не хотите потому что Мета вам не указ и вас не интересует как тут люди голосуют?  Вы считаете что можно игнорировать результаты голосования на Мете? Если я как-то вас нет так понял, то слушаю

Comment: Мне кажется, было бы здорово перевести эти цитаты

Comment: @diraria если есть желание, добавьте перевод (я не думаю что это поможет, вреда большого не будет)

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю закрывать с формулировкой <kbd>Непонятна суть вопроса</kbd>, а в комментариях оставлять следующее сообщение:

> Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. **Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить.** Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. **Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.***

Comment: Фраза «_Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно._» – лишняя, также как и «Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе.», «Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение». Почему? Потому что это осуждающие выражения. Мы не учим людей жизни, и не можем говорить, что и кому делать. Мы лишь можем констатировать допущенные ошибки.

Comment: Также требуется перефразировтаь «Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.», так как эта фраза не всегда верна – https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/.