# Нужно ли закрывать вопросы, похожие на дубликаты

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

Существуют вопросы, которые очень уж похожи на дубликаты, при этом последний из таких вопросов не четко сформулирован.

Пример вопросов:

[Инициализация двумерного массива по спирали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450354/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8)

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455117/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8

Что нужно делать в таких случаях: отмечать вопрос как дубликат или же закрывать вопрос до максимально четкой формализации задачи автором, а уже потом закрывать/не закрывать по обстоятельствам?

Comment: Метные Войны Эпизод 5: Спиральные матрицы наносят ответный удар.

Comment: [Метные Войны Эпизод 6: Возвращение Влада](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455176/181472)

Comment: Опять... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455199/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И уже существующий вопрос, и потенциальная копия (копии) - это оффтопик. SO - не решебник задач. SO - это база ответов на вопросы, возникающие в процессе разработки ПО. Это уже обсуждалось [на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/177221), и никто не высказался за решение задач при *полном отсутствии* усилий со стороны автора.

У решения "закрыть как копию" есть несколько неочевидных минусов:

- Закрытие с причиной "копия" автоматически продлевает время жизни вопроса с 9 до 30 дней.
- Неотрицательный баланс голосов на "копии" продлевает ее время жизни до 365 дней.
- Если при этом к вопросу есть хотя бы два комментария - он остается жить вечно.
- Точно так же продлевает жизнь вопроса установка блокировки.

И вот за пару часов мы имеем три вопроса "решите мне задачу", которые не умрут никогда.

Что стоит делать - руководствоваться [инструкцией от jfs](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/177221):

- *полное отсутствие* демонстрации усилий со стороны автора вопроса — *голосовать «против»*
- не слишком полезен из-за искусственных ограничений не встречающихся на практике — *голосовать «против»*
- содержит несколько отдельных вопросов — *оставить комментарий к вопросу*, чтобы автор сначала попытался решить задачу самостоятельно, и при возникновении конкретных проблем, задавал бы более специфичные вопросы
- не хватает контекста, чтобы краткий хороший ответ оставить — *закрыть как слишком обширный или неясный*

Не хотите превратить SO в решебник для халявщиков - голосуйте против. Голоса против за вопросы ничего не стоят.

Comment: Этот подход не решает проблему. На ru.SO есть те, кто считают, что решать домашние задания за пользователей - это нормально. Посмотрите комментарии к http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/450354/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8 . А если так, то ru.SO все равно превратиться в решебник

Comment: пост по ссылке оформлен как "на собеседовании спросили". соответственно, контекст другой - найти "красивое" решение. и даже при этом в комментах - попытки закрыть вопрос. остальные два - неприкрытые дз.

Comment: Вопрос по ссылке был закрыт. А потом его переоткрыли

Comment: @DmitriySimushev его переоткрыли потому что на нем нет ни одного минуса (т.е. его закрывали, но не минусовали - а стоило бы). 5 человек отдало голос за закрытие. будь у вопроса -5 к моменту закрытия - никто бы и не подумал его переоткрывать. потому что переоткрыть заминусованную работу за автора и ответить на нее - это верный способ получить еще и минус на свой ответ.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вчитайтеь в мой ответ - такое не надо закрывать вообще. надо тупо минусовать. если вы особо жестоки - то минусовать и ответы, чтобы не поощерять отвечат на "решите за меня"

Comment: С минусами вопросу я согласен, но минусовать ответы... Как-то слишком уж жестко и не справедливо к отвечающим

Comment: @DmitriySimushev минус - это не оценка "качества". это способ показать что вы не одобряете поведение того, кто ответ оставил. говорю вам как [evil user #24](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/300464/most-evil-users)

Comment: Я немного злее вас буду(#13) ;)