# Как отвечать на вопросы про "домашнее задание"?

Tags: обсуждение

Формально, правила сообщества не запрещают пользователям задавать вопросы про "домашнее задание" (вопросы вида "вот условие задачи, дайте готовое решение").

Вот в [этом вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) уже обсуждалась проблема работы за автора. Однако там речь шла о закрытии/не закрытии (судьбе) самого вопроса. Как результат, сообществом было принято решение "*минусовать, но закрывать только совсем уж плохие вопросы*". Как следствие, такие вопросы имеют право на жизнь и я с этим согласен.

Однако, "домашние задания" несут мало пользы сообществу, за исключением тех несчастных, которым достался тот же вариант из методички. Более того, отвечая готовым кодом на такие вопросы мы поощряем авторов к stackoverflow-driven-development, что не способствует ни росту сообщества, ни обогащению его знатоками.

Вопрос собственно в том, **как нужно отвечать** на такие вопросы (насколько подробно, развернуто, ...)? Должны ли ответы на нормальные вопросы и ответы на домашние задания концептуально отличаться?

Дополнительный вопрос, что нужно делать с уже существующими *ответами* на "домашние задания".

Comment: К.О. с нами. Их нужно вовремя сдавать преподавателю.

Comment: @igumnov, вопрос отвечать или не отвечать на такие вопросы))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа за автора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @PashaPash, я бы не сказал, что это дубль. Вопрос "Работа за автора" несколько шире

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: я не вижу разницы: не могли Вы по пунктам перечислить возможные отличия ([мой ответ](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233/23044) говорит, что нужно делать с вопросами про  *“домашнее задание”*)

Comment: Ваш ответ сводится к "_минусовать но закрывать только в крайнем случае_", т.е. домашниее задание имеет право на жизнь. Мой вопрос несколько в другом: а стоит ли вообще _отвечать_ на такие вопросы?

Comment: @jfs, иными словами, меня больше интересует, что делать с _ответами на домашнее задание_, а не с самим домашним заданием (что как раз покрывается вопросом [работа за автора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)).

Comment: Если Вам не нравятся *выводы* это не значит, что это другой вопрос -- вы можете добавить свой ответ там. И мой ответ говорит: если вопрос хороший, то не важно задали ли его кому-то как домашнее задание или нет. "Крайние случаи" тут ни причём.

Comment: @jfs, а я разве сказал, что мне не нравятся выводы?) Я согласен с тем, что домашние задания имеют право на жизнь (кстати, ваш ответ предполагает всего _один_ случай, когда такие вопросы стоит закрывать). Как бы то ни было, относиться к домашним заданиям так же как и к нормальным вопросам, на мой взгляд неправильно. И отвечать на такие вопросы нужно совсем не так же как и на "нормальные" (см. текст вопроса с пояснениями "почему").

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: от того что Вы думаете, что вопрос, который где-то был задан как домашнее задание, является каким-то особенным -- то есть различие  в наших точках зрения -- не делает Ваш вопрос уникальным: **ещё раз**, если Вы не согласны (имеете полное право), то оставьте новый ответ к уже существующему вопросу про абсолютно тоже самое.

Comment: @jfs, ваш ответ покрывает только "_сами вопросы_", но не говорит ничего об _ответах на такие вопросы_ (и это нормально, потому что [вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0) именно так и сформулирован). Это, по-сути, две стороны одной и той же проблемы: "решения дз на ru.SO", но это точно не дубликат.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если суть этого вопроса - это что делать с **ответами** на домашние задания - то надо было так и написать. У вас выделено "*как нужно отвечать на такие вопросы*" - и ответ jfs полностью и подробно это раскрывает.

Comment: @PashaPash, добавил дополнительный вопрос. Я считаю, что мы сначала должны понять как _отвечать_ на дз, а уже потом решать, что делать с существующими ответами. Собственно ответ _jfs_ вообще не затрагивает проблему **ответов** на такие вопросы.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev IMHO, вы не понимаете суть ответа jfs. и суть решения сообщества - тоже. Вы предполагаете, что сам факт, что вопрос возник из методички, а не в результате проявления реальной проблемы, *чем-то* делает этот вопрос лучше (или хуже). Или делает ответы на него лучше или хуже. И что из-за этого они заслуживают какого-то особого обращения

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Что делать с вопросами?

Что произойдет, если кто-то запостит ужасный, кривой, плохо сформулированный вопрос, без попыток решить его самостоятельно?

В случае, если из вопроса видно, что автор, не студент, а просто ленивый эникейщик, который просто сваливает на SO свою работу, и при этом не заморачивается даже нормально оформить вопрос - вопрос быстро заминусуют и закроют.

Почему в ситуации, когда автор вопроса - ленивый студент, который тупо пропустил лекции и практику, и теперь пытается "сдать лабы" нужно поступать иначе? Человек не прилагает никаких усилий - он просто выделяет в ворде текст своего задания, пейстит, игнорирует 3-4 решения такой же лабы (как посчитать среднее во второй колонке??), которые ему показывает сайт, и постит "вопрос".

Да, давайте будем поощерять такое поведение! Будем наставлять его на путь истинный (раз уж толпа преподавателей в универе не смогла это сделать), выбивать ради него новые фишки движка (форматирование кода в комментах!), договариваться не минусовать (ага, щас)....

Kill it with fire!

---

## Что делать c ответами:

То же самое, что и с ответами на остальные вопросы.

---

Хотите принести людям пользу - откройте неотвеченные вопросы по [your-favorite-tag](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/your-favorite-tag). И ответьте хотя бы на пару из них.

Comment: К сожалению, сообщество считает, что домашние задания имеют право на жизнь. см. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0 . А раз так, то можно хотя бы договориться о том, как стоит отвечать на такие вопросы

Comment: @DmitriySimushev перечитайте внимательно ответ jfs по ссылке. и мой заодно. Сообщество считает, что домашние задания - это обычные вопросы. Нет разницы - домашнее это задание, или нет. Если это плохой вопрос - значит с ним надо поступить как с плохим вопросом. Если это хороший вопрос - то как с хорошим вопросом.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Домашние задания имеют права на жизнь, но не потому, что они домашние задания, а если они имеют ценность помимо этого. Если нет — я лично ценности в домашних заданиях не вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Пристыдить не желанием понимать суть вопроса и дать подробное объяснение как и почему, код использовать по минимуму.

Comment: Унизить - это не наш метод. См. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: Мне было бы очень стыдно, если бы я попросил код, а мне сказали, что я не очень разумно себя веду и для самосовершенствования мне небходимо писать код самому. Для меня бы это послужило стимулом для более подробного самостоятельного(!) изучения вопроса. А агрессия это и вправду ужасно.

Comment: То, что вы описали, это "пристыдить". А унизить, это немного другое

Comment: Прошу прощение за неккоректную формулировку. Исправил.

Comment: Да пристыжать бесполезно... У него задание. Задание надо быстренько сделать (любой ценой) и бежать дальше в WOF резаться... Таких пристыжать бесполезно. А те, кто хотят выполнить задание, они и вопросы другие задавать будут... Вобщем я согласен с предложение @avp: не отвечать, не плюсовать, не минусовать...

Comment: Может тогда метку какую-нибудь вешать с объяснением? Или давать ссылку почему игнор

Answer (score 1):

Предложу альтернативную позицию, а то слишком мало драмы.

Я считаю, что нужно минусовать не только вопросы про домашнее задание, но и полноценные ответы на них. Причем даже правильные ответы. Исключением из этого правила могут быть только ответы, которые автору придется существенно дорабатывать перед сдачей "д.з." (алгоритмы, общие идеи и подходы, ...). Это позволит добиться следующих результатов:

1. Те, кто отвечают на вопросы ради репутации, дважды подумают перед ответом.
2. Автор вопроса получит ответ на свой вопрос и пойдет гулять дальше.
3. Заминусованные вопросы без положительных ответов удаляться (или я ошибаюсь) движком через некоторое время.

Comment: А тут много народу задерживаются, кто отвечает не ради репутации? Чуть вопрос посложнее задашь, не из методичек, и ответа нет.

Comment: @dsnk, зависит от тематики вопроса и от того, насколько он грамотно сформулирован. Вопросы из серии "_вот портянка кода, что тут не так_" интересны только "охотникам за кармой".

Answer (score 1):

*Отвечать* на домашние задания нужно ровно так же, как и на любые другие вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

(По обсуждению в чате)

Думаю, нам надо просто договориться, что профи кодом на них (например, отмеченных тегом "учебное-задание") не отвечают, вопрос не плюсуется и не минусуется.  Оставим их "студентам" (в самом широком смысле). Не уверен, что это во всех случаях будет полезно вопрошающему, но наверняка развивает отвечающих.

Пусть тренируются и зарабатывают репу. Оцениваем код и пояснения ключевых для понимания темы моментов.

Профи  лишь комментируют и наставляют словами, подсказывают в каком направлении мыслить.  Жаль, нельзя вставлять отформатированные фрагменты кода в комментарии (с этим что-то надо бы придумать (ссылки в pastebin?)).

Возможно стоит ограничить срок жизни таких тем (и материала в pastebin), скажем, месяц. По истечении тема удаляется (без потери очков авторами **ответов**) и никому больше не мозолит глаза.

Вот, только не знаю, может ли существующий движок автоматизировать такие действия.

Comment: Иногда возникает желание написать такой ответ, который формально правилен, но автор, скорее всего, не сможет его использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну это совсем зверство)

Comment: На мой взгляд, подход описанный в данном ответ нужно использовать совместно с http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/233/182771 . Думаю они дополняют друг-друга

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, http://www.cyberforum.ru/vb-net/thread1014838.html#post5374782

Comment: @avp, в целом я полностью согласен с вашем ответом, за одним исключением: мне кажется, что удалять ничего не нужно. Просто через год возникнет та же проблема))

Comment: Возможно. На удалении я не настаиваю.

Comment: Домашние задания подразумевают предварительное прохождение курса лекций + практических занятий. Если кто-то притаскивает ДЗ на SO, и просто вываливает его тут без попыток решить самостоятельно - то ни в каких наставлениях он не нуждается. Он нуждается в коде, чтобы можно было сдать лабу.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ок, вопрос про "обработать массив" строк не удалили. Вы думаете, это спасло от появления кучи дубликатов с чуть-чуть измененным условием?

Comment: @PashaPash, дубликаты можно закрывать с формулировкой "дубликат" ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я к тому, что проблема возникнет через год в любом случае.

Comment: @Qwertiy: [как раз в тему](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/180063/10105).

Comment: @VladD, ага :)​