# Минусовать ли правильные ответы, если в вопросе нет кода, который не получается у автора?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, голоса-против, принятые-ответы

Как я понимаю, по правилам SO, если автор спрашивает что-то по коду, например: "Как отобразить блок `N` если кликнуть 10 раз на кнопку `M`", то автор вопроса обязан предоставить код (пусть и никчемный по его мнению), который он пытался написать, но он (код) не приводит к желаемому результату.

В ином случае получается, что это работа за автора. А вопросы, где работа за автора, как правило, закрываются. Кто-то иногда пишет в комментариях таких вопросах даже пишет - идите на фриланс биржу и т.д.))

Если я не прав - поправьте.

Если я прав, то в связи с этим как раз и возникает вопрос: а что делать с теми, кто так или иначе ответил на вопрос? Да, ответил правильно. Но при этом сделал за автора работу, что против правил, по сути.

Следует ли как-то наказывать таких людей? Как? Хоть и помощь, но в то же время и получается из-за таких людей становится все больше безмозглых "специалистов", которые везде постят свои вопросы, а потом копипастят ответы себе в проекты.

Типичный представитель:

[Изменение высоты блока по мере прокрутки страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478976/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)

или

[Создание блока по клику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479358/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

Автор, такое ощущение, что просто всем дает задание. Пишет: "я тут заготовку для удобства накидал"....И всё. Делайте за него, значит. Просто наглость. А давать правильные ответы на это: Тупость. Имхо)

В общем, что делать и как быть?

Comment: Вот пример такого вопроса с отличными ответами: [Парсер математических выражений](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23842)

Answer (score 25):

Для начала о тематике. Вопросы жанра "[работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)" — **разрешены**. Если кто-то закрывает подобные вопросы, то они — нарушители правил. Оба вопроса, приведённые в качестве примера — совершенно нормальные.

Теперь о голосах. Голоса можно ставить как угодно и кому угодно, на плюсы и минусы нет абсолютно никаких правил, кроме одного — не преследовать плюсами и минусами одного участника. В остальном каждый волен ставить голоса хоть по желанию левой пятки.

И вот теперь можно о традициях. На СО считается "морально допустимым" минусовать ответы на оффтопичные вопросы. Кроме того, что это демотивирует от написания ответов на оффтопик (а ответы провоцируют новые подобные вопросы, что, разумеется, плохо), эти минусы ещё и упрощают последующее удаление вопросов и вручную, и автоматически.

Наконец, выскажу своё личное мнение. Если ответ дан на вопрос, разрешённый правилами, если ответ основательный, то ставить минус такому ответу только за то, что кому-то не нравятся простые вопросы — это свинство, и подобное поведение вредит качеству сайта: как известно, самые простые вопросы являются самыми популярными, а минусы усложняют поиск подобных вопросов. Но каждый волен поступать как хочет.

Comment: По приведенной вами ссылке принятый ответ — просто рассуждения на тему. Насколько я его понимаю, предлагается отвлечься от того, что это домашнее задание, и что в нём нет кода — и смотреть на общую полезность вопроса и ответов.

Comment: @Discord вы мнение о простых вопросах написали, а я говорю в целом, вообще о вопросах, о любых. Если вопрос и ответ полезен - то  можно и оставить. Даже простой. Я хоть и не любитель минусовать, но это кажется немного неправильным и многое вообще бы удалял)) **Оффтопя**: Как я когда-то сказал - никто не пользуется поиском и сразу фигачит вопрос. Однако на них дают ответ, а не указывают что дубль. Вопросы часто уникальны для конкретного юзера и многие, как следствие, вообще не несут остальным пользы, но оставляют и отвечают на них.

Comment: @Discord А вопросы сделайте мне в целом зачастую получаются гибридом между частичной уникальной для юзера проблемой и вопросом который никогда никто не будет искать и не ищет вдогонку с тем, что лень пытаться написать самому))

Comment: Есть люди, которые минусуют ответы по каким-то своим внутренним правилам, но неверно утверждать что это традиция всего сайта. Я активный участник SO и считаю "морально НЕдопустимым" минусовать ответы по причинам, независимым от самого ответа и его места. Я бы не сказал, что вопросы жанра "работа за автора" -- разрешены (они не запрещены). Смысл [моего ответа](http://goo.gl/WqSNEn), что не важно к какому жанру вопрос относится, если это хороший вопрос (но как правило вопросы в этом жанре -- это плохие вопросы) и лекарство хуже болезни (полезные вопросы закрываются, а мусор продолжает расти).

Answer (score 21):

Нет, не минусовать. Человек старался, писал ответ - с чего он за это должен получить минус?

Comment: Но это ж не по правилам. Тогда зачем закрывать аналогичные вопросы, где все сводится к Помогите напишите мне, жаловаться что работа за автора и пр, если мы сами подобным образом (решая за автора) провоцируем на создание аналогичных  вопросов? Какое-то противоречие самих себе. Своим же правилам

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Правила придумываем мы и для нас. Если правило где-то не работает, его нужно уточнить.

Comment: @VladD Вот я их и не понимаю)) Следя за некоторыми вопросами у меня происходит когнити́вный диссона́нс. Одни вопросы закрываются, другие, абсолютно такие же по параметрам - нет. Возможно я не все понимаю, поэтому лично я буду продолжать как и раньше просто отвечать на вопросы, а компетентые люди уж разберутся, что самим вопросом делать) Ну ответами тож.

Answer (score 15):

> Если я не прав - поправьте.

Вы не правы по обоим пунктам:

1. Нет требования, чтобы полезные вопросы жанра «Как сделать X, при условии Y» должны содержать код. Более того, присутствие кода, указывало бы, что исходная проблема не была достаточно изолирована и вопрос содержит бесполезные для большинства будущих читателей детали: eсли проблема, была корректно изолирована, то ответ либо известен автору либо нет и поэтому  попытки решения в виде кода скорее всего, содержат ошибки никак не относящиеся к исходному вопросу (и поэтому бесполезны для данного вопроса)
2. Нет такой причины закрытия «работа за автора». [Закрытие вопросов по подобным причинам не работает (вредно в целом для сайта) и если вопрос полезный, то не важно содержит ли он потуги автора или нет](http://goo.gl/WqSNEn).

> Следует ли как-то наказывать таких людей?

Старайтесь мыслить в терминах результатов, а не моральных абсолютов, а именно: улучшает ли ваше конкретное действие сайт или нет — вне зависимости от того как вы правила сайта воспринимаете («я следовал приказам» это оправдание палачей — смотрите на последствия вместо этого).
 А чтобы узнать последствия, посмотрите на историю SO, который уже много лет существует и где уже многие вещи пробовали не раз (результат моих раскопок: если вы не садист (то есть если процесс наказания не является самоцелью), то не только бесполезно пытаться наказать авторов вопросов *в этом жанре*, но и вредно — полезные популярные вопросы закрываются, а бесполезный мусор продолжает расти каждый день).

Answer (score 8):

У подобных вопросов несколько проблем:

1. они часто имеют низкое качество;
2. иногда ответ может занимать большой объём (часто могут быть довольно общими);
3. не понятно, в чём проблема автора, и приходится раскрывать все варианты или угадывать.

Поэтому сами вопросы и стоит закрывать для уточнения. Если вопрос будет уточнён, то можно будет написать короткий корректный ответ, а не статью-исследование.

Если же кто-то ответил, то **не вижу смысла минусовать ответ**. Этот ответ всё же может помочь многим.
Считать, что кто-то "охотится" за репутацией на таких вопросах? А в чём проблема, если ответ ценный?
Считать, что этим идёт поощрение разработки через SO? Опять же, если связка вопрос/ответ полезна, то пусть будут. Если задающий вопрос будет продолжать нагло выспрашивать ответы, то многим будет просто лень помогать такому человеку, и скорее всего, отвечать ему будут всё медленнее.

Может быть, есть ещё какие-то причины "наказывать" отвечающего, но лично я не вижу ничего плохого в хороших ответах на вопросах. Это проблема не отвечающего, это проблема задающего.

Answer (score 5):

Минусовать стоит в том случае если ответ:

1. не правильный
2. не несет в себе никакого смысла и не является ответом
3. является копией чьего-то ответа

Если человек старался - это еще не говорит о том, что его старания оправданы и достойны вознаграждения. А вот относительно простых вопросов иногда прям не приятно...ну спросил человек что-то простое, ну не получилось у него. Зачем минусовать? Мне проще быстро набросать ответ, чем заминусовать. Да, есть вопросы, абсолютно не информативные, есть и ответы такие. Но если есть ответ на вопрос, решающий проблему, то не думаю, что стоит минусовать такой ответ.
В общем, все просто:

> На stackoverflow есть правила и их нужно соблюдать.