# Должны ли мы минусовать?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, голоса-против

…тех, кто хочет получить ответ на свой вопрос без каких-либо попыток поискать/попытаться написать код? Только потому, что ему просто "что-то очень надо", прямо "вообще срочняк", "горит", "помогите команду написать"…
И тех, кто дает ответы на такого рода вопросы.

(В таком плане)

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2246/%d0%9c%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f?rq=1

Comment: @АндрейNOP вообще-то по той ссылке говорится про минусы ответам, а не вопросам...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну и здесь тоже про ответы спрашивается. Вообще, у этого вопроса 2 дубликата - один про минусы на вопросы, второй - про минусы на ответы. Надо закрыть и просто поправить список дубликатов :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP а где второй?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хороший вопрос. Я не искал, т.к. по Мете пока плохо ориентируюсь, а много времени тратить неохота :)

Comment: Все эти "срочняки" и "очень надо" нужно выпиливать из вопроса за ненадобностью, я считаю. Для предлагаемой правки значимость может и недостаточно велика, но будучи 2к+ "я б выпилил".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы путаете вопросы без кода и вопросы из серии "что-то очень надо".

Дело в том что есть множество хороших вопросов для которых любой код будет лишним, и на сайте такие вопросы разрешены.

К вопросу же из серии "что-то очень надо" очень легко добавить случайный код, и авторы таких вопросов частенько так и делают - но вопрос от этого лучше не становится.

Так вот. Ставить минусы первым только за то что автор не захотел добавлять в вопрос визуальный мусор - неправильно. Ставить минусы вторым - можно и нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Мне почему-то льстит этот ответ https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2247/266177.

Я против того чтобы минусовать ответы на заезженные или некачественные вопросы, ибо одно дело не хороший вопрос а другое ответ, если ответ качественный и решающий проблему, то зачем его минусовать? Человек ведь, и правда постарался чтобы понять вопроса и ответить на него. Так что я против того чтобы минусовать качественные ответы на некачественные вопросы!

Comment: Понимаете в чем прикол: потом как грибы после дождя появляются специалисты "яжтыжпрограммисты", которые даже не понимают того, что они делают, или будут делать.

Comment: Ну такие есть и будут всегда и проблема тут не в тех кто отвечает, а если не ответят, то тех кто спросил это не накажет...