# Голосование против. Возможность опротестовать

Tags: обсуждение, хэшкод

И снова здравствуйте ;^) На этот раз с сайта [math.hashcode.ru](http://math.hashcode.ru) Кому-то я пришёлся не по душе и подряд [три моих вопроса](http://math.hashcode.ru/users/1313/jktu) получили по минусу (не надо кидаться добавлять ещё минусов - заранее большое спасибо за непредвзятость и неспешность), причём другие мои подобные вопросы остались без минуса (но не в этом суть: хотя минус можно было дать как один - на один вопрос, так и 6 - на большее число вопросов; остановились на среднем ;^)

По сути даже одному вопросу не за что ставить минус: имею в виду:
http://math.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading3

и тот факт, что первый пользователь в рейтинге ([falcao](http://math.hashcode.ru/users/)) - и не только он один - многократно отвечали на все те вопросы (более чем на три) - и никак не дали знать, что они этими вопросами не довольны - ничто в их поведении не указывает на недовольство.

Воспользовался вчера формой обратной связи, но всего там перечислено 3 средства - и в долгом ожидании действия первого воспользовался вторым.

> …тех, кто хочет получить ответ на свой вопрос без каких-либо попыток
>   поискать/попытаться написать код? Только потому, что ему просто
>   "что-то очень надо", прямо "вообще срочняк", "горит", "помогите
>   команду написать"…
>   [Должны-ли-мы-минусовать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7344/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Ну, только один-единственный [вопрос без "кода"](http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/165113/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5-40-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-10-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8) (математического). **НО!** Мне на него первыми двумя комментариями не дали прямых ответов, вот так:

> типовая задача на гипергеометрическое распределение...
>
> (23 часа назад)all_exist @all_exist Ok, изучу
>
> (23 часа назад)Jktu @Jktu: ответьте последовательно на такие вопросы.
>
> 1) Сколькими способами из 40 человек можно выбрать 20?
>
> 2) Сколькими способами их же можно выбрать так, чтобы среди них было 5
>   отличников и 15 не отличников?
>
> 3) Чему равна вероятность? (23 часа назад)falcao @falcao Я так и
>   начинал. Ответ на 1-ый вопрос получился С (20 из 40) = 40! / (20! *
>   20!) = 30-значное целое, причём только 5 последних знаков - нули.
>
> (23 часа назад)Jktu @Jktu: это число большое, но его не надо находить
>   в явном виде. Надо найти второе (тоже выразить через сочетания), а
>   потом у частного многие факториалы посокращаются. При практическом
>   вычислении полезно раскладывать числитель и знаменатель на простые
>   множители. В конце получится дробь, у которой надо указать сначала
>   точное значение, а потом приближённое.

***В-общем, извините и спасибо.***

Comment: 1.Причем тут мета ruSO?
2.Что вы хотите(понимаю, высказать недовольство, но вы не пишите что вы хотите прямо, а пишите "В-общем, извините и спасибо.")
3.Хэшкод живой? Почему вы не пишите на [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?
4.Вопрос к другим пользователям: почему hashcode живой? Почему его не переместили в SE?

Comment: @Anton238 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316022/whats-to-become-of-the-remaining-hashcode-ru-sites

Comment: @Anton238 Просто я обретался на [http://math.hashcode.ru/](http://math.hashcode.ru/) и там прочёл [http://math.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading21](http://math.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading21)  Ну, там было перечислено три варианта "Как оставить отзыв, задать вопрос, сделать предложение по сайту": первый исчерпал, попробовал второй и, похоже сработал - репутация вернулась откуда то :^) 3.) Во-первых, я там давно зарегистрирован и, к тому же, ничего не сообщали о переезде. Во-вторых, как сейчас посмотрел: одно на русском, другое - на англе, всё-таки.

Comment: @Anton238 при том, что Николас на старых сайтах всё не может ссылки поменять. А они сюда ведут.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Я правильно понимаю, что сначала Николас "основал" сайты, похожие на ruSO и сеть SE, а потом SE выкупила их и Николас перешел к ним на работу? Не знал, интересно. Можно где-то  почитать про историю ruSO?

Comment: @Anton238 Да, все так.Теперь сайт математики принадлежит SE, но использует старый движок и никак не развивается. Какого-то сборника информации по истории сайта нет, есть только разрозненные статьи на новостных сайтах и сообщения в чате. Впрочем, это уже мало относится к вопросу.

Comment: @Anton238 `Можно где-то почитать про историю ruSO?` —
 да, я в своё время [наткнулся на интервью](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43516495#43516495) от 2015-го года на тему превращения Хэшкода в Ru.SO. В ответ Николас рассказал дополнительные детали (начиная с https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43530470#43530470 и ниже).